# Getting the Path to WEB-INF on Openshift Tomcat 6 - JBoss EWS 1.0

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, openshift

I previously used the following to get my context path on Tomcat-5.0.28 and earlier:
    String context_path = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/");
This worked to return the path to that folder.
But on OpenShift (Tomcat 6 - JBoss EWS 1.0) this returns

```
/var/lib/openshift/53.*context_id_here*..18/jbossews/null
```

The null should be:

```
work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF
```

How can I get the path to the WEB-INF folder on OpenShift using JBOSS/Tomcat?

A little background information:  When I ran this struts webapp on my own Tomcat server, I deployed a appname.war file in the webapps directory and waited for it to expand (since I had set that option in the server.xml file).  Then I move a folder to webapps/appname/ folder with xml files I need to read and write to for my app to work.  On OpenShift I used jar xvf appname.war to extract the war file by hand (because that's the default and I don't know how to change it), and then moved the files folder (from the same directory as the war file in my folder after a git add and push) to work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/
This is causing a NullPointerException for me when trying to use that path as shown above.

Comment: “getServletContext().getRealPath("") - This way will not work if content is being made available from a .war archive. getServletContext() will be null.”  Is this also true if the war is unpacked using the jar command?  There is no server.xml file (that I can find) to change the settings in this OpenShift cartridge.

Comment: There is no `.openshift/config/server.xml` file in the cartridge directory, so not sure how I could specify unpack war.  Also, after creating a workaround to replace a null with the correct path and pushing a new war file, the app is now causing a ClassCastException on it's first page.

Comment: There is however a server.xml file in this position in the local project file.  Why isn't it pushed to the server?  Also, there are no autoDeploy or unpackWARs elements to set to true in the file.  Time to read the Tomcat 6.  It appears that in Tomcat 7 it is not even possible to unpack the war file at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using something like getServletContext or getRealPath, and reading it from the web root instead of trying to find the file on the physical disk.  That way your war file can run anywhere without issue.  Try looking up both of those and see if one fits your use case.

Comment: corey112358, I already use those calls.  The line of code before the getRealPath is:
`ServletContext context = getServlet().getServletContext(); 
 String context_path = context.getRealPath(File.separator+"WEB-INF"+File.separator);`